# AngularJS - function within controller isn't being called as I would expect in simple example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

For the following HTML and JS controller, why is the 'clear' button not triggering the function?

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="resetController as reset">
  <div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <button ng-click="clearName">Clear</button>
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the app.js file

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('resetController', function($scope) {
  $scope.yourName = 'Start';

  $scope.clearName = function(){
    console.log('clearing name...');
    $scope.yourName = '';
  };

});
```

Comment: `ng-click="clearName()"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clearName() is a function so you need the parenthesis.

```
<button ng-click="clearName()">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing '()', I believe you have to write the function as if it is being called, e.g.

`<button ng-click="clearName()">Clear</button>`

Additionally, I can see that you are using the controllerAS syntax, so you would normally end up with:

`<button ng-click="reset.clearName()">Clear</button>`

However, I think you need to bind the function to the controller and not the scope object in that case. e.g.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('resetController', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.yourName = 'Start';

  self.clearName = function(){
    console.log('clearing name...');
    self.yourName = '';
  };

});
```

It is a long read, but have a look at https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide.

Good luck.